# How to show logged-in user name in input form field while creating in Yii1?

Tags: php, yii

I have a form where one can upload his/her own CV files(docx/pdf).I have a drop down menu "employee name" in the from which  shows only the login user name in the list.But now i want to show the login user name in the from input field.how can i do that.Can any one give me code example.As i am very poor at coding.
Here is my from code:

```
        if($UserType == "employee")
    { 
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "status= 'active' and id = $ID";
        echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
            $model,
            'user_id',
            array(
                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                ),
                'widgetOptions' => array(
                    'data' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'user_id'),

                    'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select'),
                )

            )
        );

        }
```

[user name input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ6Ws.png) 
[logged-in user name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twLXE.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do:

First, in /protected/components, I set a session variable to store the logged-in user name:

```
public function authenticate()
{
  $user = Users::model()->find('user = ? ', array($this->username)); //user entered when trying to log in
...
}
```

If authentication is correct:

```
public function authenticate()
{
 ...
  $session = new CHttpSession;
  $session->open(); //session_start
  $session['user'] = $user; //$user is the logged-in username
 ...
}
```

In controller action create:

```
public function actionCreate(){
  $session = new CHttpSession;  
  $session->open();
  $user = $session['user'];

  ...

  $this->render('create',array(
    'user'=>$user,
    'model'=>$model,
    ...
  ));
}
```

In view (in /_form, for example):

```
...
$model->user = $user;

$form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
));
...
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'user',...); //Here, the attribute 'user' of the model $model will have the logged-in user-name
...
```

This is assuming you have an attribute called 'user' in your model. If not, then, in /model, create an auxiliary attribute 'user' in order to use this attribute in your /_form:

```
class YourModel extends CActiveRecord
{
  public $user; //$variable used to set the logged-in username
 ...
}
```